# How to remove any test from TestNG results or ITestContext

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-annotation-test

**Background:**
I am using TestNG DataProvider

**Requirement:**
Need to eliminate 1 test from the TestNG report after execution is finished.

**My Solution:**
Suppose, I need to remove the 'XYZ' test case from the report.

```
String testName = "XYZ";

private void removeTestFromResult(ITestContext context)
    {
        for (ITestNGMethod testMethodName : context.getAllTestMethods())
        {
            String testMethod = testMethodName.getMethodName().toLowerCase();

            if (testMethod.contains(testName))
            {
                if (context.getPassedTests().size() > 0)
                {
                    context.getPassedTests().removeResult(testMethodName);
                }
                if (context.getFailedTests().size() > 0)
                {
                    context.getFailedTests().removeResult(testMethodName);
                }
                if (context.getSkippedTests().size() > 0)
                {
                    context.getSkippedTests().removeResult(testMethodName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute the test and hide it from the result report you can take a look at the TestNG TestListenerAdapter. It is possible to modify the test context after execution e.g. removing unwanted tests from it. See [this link](https://www.pawangaria.com/post/testng/remove-retried-test-from-testng-report/) for a detailed example.

**TestListenerAdapter:**

```
public class MyTestListenerAdapter extends TestListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
        //TODO remove the unwanted tests from context.getPassedTests()
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
@Listeners(MyTestListenerAdapter.class)
public class MyTest {
    //Your test methods here.
}
```

[Here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) are all TestNG listeners documented. Those can be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the @Test annotation you can set enabled=false to avoid their execution:

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations